# My App function isn't reading an imported component. I get a "defined but never use" warning

Tags: reactjs

My code for some reason can't read the imported navbar component and is showing a blank page. Anyone know why? The warning I get is 'defined but never used'.

Navbar.js

```
import React from "react"

const navbar = () => {
    return(
        <nav>
            <div class="topnav">
                <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
                <a class="active" href="#home">Dining Halls</a>
                <a href="#news">Login</a>
                <a href="#contact">Signup</a>
            </div>
        </nav>
    )
}

export default navbar
```

App.js

```
import React from "react"
import "./App.css"
import navbar from "./components/navbar.js";

function App() {
  return (
    <navbar />
  );
}


export default App;
```

Comment: Rename your component to `Navbar`, The first letter must be uppercase

Comment: From the [ReactJS documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html):  "Always start component names with a capital letter. React treats components starting with lowercase letters as DOM tags".  See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48968004/421195

Comment: Voting to close as "unreproducible or caused by typo". `import navbar from "./components/navbar.js";` to `import Navbar from "./components/navbar.js";` and render as `Navbar`. React component names are PascalCased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to rename your component to Navbar instead of navbar just like Ali said. The reason is that, by convention React will use any jsx in lowercase as if it is an html tag, not a component. All components you use should go in PascalCase in order to React understand it is a component and not just an html tag.